# An organizational chart to ensure central management of laboratories in a college

Tags: administration, medicine, lab-management

I was asked the other day to suggest how different labs in our college should be centrally managed, or what organizational chart would be suitable, to make all these labs abide by input from the quality assurance department in the college. We all know that charts can never improve management by themselves, but what I am looking for is a consensus or an estimate of what such an organizational structure might look like. What would be the best organization structure to facilitate better management of labs and have them follow a unified code with a view of **accreditation** in the future.

The college is a medical one which has several faculties with their respective labs inside: anatomy, chemistry, physiology, microbiology, pathology, pharmacology, computers, and medical research unit.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Notes: below are some key considerations:**

- Lab accreditation
- Lab devices, equipment, materials, procurement
- Lab personnel training and qualifying
- IT support
- Calibration and maintenance
- Lab safety
- Store

**PS**
- No need to provide a chart to illustrate the organizational structure, a structured text as lists would be fine.